# Piping from a variable instead of file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, pipe

Is ther any way in Powershell to pipe in from an virable instead of a file?

There are commands that I need to pipe into another command, right now that is done by first creating a file with the additional commands, and then piping that file into the original command. Code looks somehting like this now:

```
$val = "*some command*" + "`r`n" + "*some command*" + "`r`n" + "*some command*"

New-Item -name Commands.txt -type "file" -value $val

$command = @'
db2cmd.exe /C '*custom db2 command* < \Commands.txt > \Output.xml'
'@

Invoke-Expression -Command:$command
```

So instead of creating that file, can I somehow just pipe in `$val` insatead of Commands.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$val = @("*some command*1","*some command2*","*some command3*")  
$val | % { db2cmd.exe /C $_ > \Output.xml }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not behave exactly the way needed to. This will open a new db2cmd for each of the commands in $val and run them seperatly. It needs to open just one db2cmd-window and first call the *custom db2 command* and after that each of the commands in $val in sequential order, all within the same db2cmd-window.

Comment: If you are worried about overwriting your output change line 2 to   
`$val | % { db2cmd.exe /C $_ >> \Output.xml }`  

so the output is appended. Otherwise perhaps Duncan's suggestion will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pipe in from $val provided you use `Write-Output` or its shorthand `echo`, but it may also be worth trying passing the commands directly on the command line. Try this (and if it doesn't work I can delete the answer):

```
PS C:\> filter db2cmd() { $_ | db2cmd.exe ($args -replace '(\\*)"','$1$1\"') }

PS C:\> $val = @"
>> *custom db2 command*
>> *some command*
>> *some command*
>> *some command*
>> "@
>>
PS C:\> db2cmd /C $val > \Output.xml
```

What happens here is that Windows executables receive their command line from a single string. If you run them from cmd.exe you cannot pass newlines in the argument string, but Powershell doesn't have that restriction so with many programs you can actually pass multiple lines as a single argument. I don't know `db2cmd.exe` so it might not work here.

The strange bit of string replacement is to handle any double quotes in the arguments: Powershell doesn't quote them and the quoting rules expected by most exe files are a bit bizarre.

The only limitation here would be that $val must not exceed about 32,600 characters and cannot contain nulls. Any other restrictions (such as whether non-ascii unicode characters work) would depend on the application.

Failing that:

```
echo $val | db2cmd.exe /C '*custom db2 command*' > \Output.xml
```

may work, or you can use it in combination with the filter I defined at the top:

```
echo $val | db2cmd  /C '*custom db2 command*' > \Output.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me some more ideas to try out, havent got it to work yet tho. echo wont work since after the *custom db2 command* it does not return to the prompt, its expecting input immediately, good idéa tho!